# SeleniumIDE was disabled by firefox as unsigned, how to get it back?

Tags: firefox, selenium, plugins, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I started my firefox browser this am and got a message about unsigned stuff and it disabled my selniumIDE plugin.
There was a mention of a way to reenable it using about:config (in the address bar) but I am not not sure now what setting could be changed to enable it?

I searched through the options provided by using about:config (in the address bar) but I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but just so you know, Selenium IDE has been revamped and can now be reliably installed from the Firefox add-ons site: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/ ... when I've installed it, there haven't been any issues around being unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing

You can toggle the setting **xpinstall.signatures.required** to false to allow unsigned addons to load.  Note that in Firefox 44, that option isn't available.  In that case, you should use the developer version of Firefox.  [Developer Version](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/developer/)

Comment: Note that based on testing in Firefox 44 Beta, this option remains available in Firefox 44. Perhaps it will be removed in Firefox 45.

Comment: I was going by this statement in the link above: "Firefox 44: Release and Beta versions of Firefox will not allow unsigned extensions to be installed, with no override.".  

I assume this will be at some point in the future.

Comment: I had assumed that. It appears Mozilla is not keeping that link up to date with what they are actually doing (if the cut-over was really happening in FF44 then ` xpinstall.signatures.required` should not be functional in beta, as they say it will not be). The switch to absolutely not permitting unsigned add-ons to be installed has been a slipping target throughout this process.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simply reinstall the IDE by downloading and installing from

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox didn't support unsigned addon anymore. But in firefox 43, we have still have option to use unverified addons. 
1)type about:config in address bar of firefox.
2)Accept the risk
3)Search for xpinstall.signatures.required.
4)Set it's value to false by double clicking on it.
5) Restart browser.